# DataBase Pooling - Connecting To A Mysql Database In Spring3 MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a mysql database on my first Spring Project and I seem to be overlooking something really simple.

I have this bean in my application-context.xml file which is commented out!

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

I know this is going to sound stupid, but in order to create a class that connects to a Mysql database using JDBC and the or the Spring JDBCTemplate, what do I do from here?

I am confused about how to populate properties in the bean above, do I do it in a superclass like this and then extend my subclasses from it.

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class JdbcDao {
     protected DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
     JdbcDao(){
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name");
         dataSource.setUsername("bcash");
         dataSource.setPassword("");        
     }    
}
```

I am confused so any help is truly apprecated,

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JdbcTemplate Best Practices](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms) for further info.

Nutshell: no, your DAO wouldn't create a new datasource via `new`; that defeats the purpose of using Spring. Implementations should be injected, not instantiated directly; roughly:

```
public class TheDaoImpl implements TheDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of TheDao follow...
}
```

Then in your Spring config (if not using annotations), also roughly:

```
<bean id="theDao" class="com.bar.plugh.TheDaoImpl" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

*(This uses a setter; you could also use an annotation and skip the XML config.)*

You could also use [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) as your base class and save more energy.

I recommend going over the [Data access with JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-introduction) reference docs (if you're using JDBC), or the corresponding section that deals directly with your ORM choice.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the answer, I think what I might be asking is how does one configure the dataSource? is that done by filling in the vales in the context-xml file?

Comment: @user866190 Yes, although it looks like it was expecting to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tomcat as your application server you can do something more like this.

Define the connection with the user name/password in your server's context.xml file (as opposed to in the application):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/resourceNameToUse"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="<UserName>"
          password="<Password>"
          driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name"
          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="Select 1"
          useCompression="true" />
```

Then when you configure Spring you create a data source that looks up the resource defined above using JNDI:

```
  <bean id="targetDataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" 
              value="java:comp/env/jdbc/resourceNameToUse"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
      <ref local="targetDataSource"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

At this point you can create an instance of your JdbcTemplate as a Spring bean that references your data source:

```
  <bean id="jdbcTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
  </bean>
```

If you are using Spring 3 you can simply mark JdbcTemplate in your DAO as `@AutoWired` and Spring will match the variable name to the id of the bean you have defined and inject the JdbcTemplate for you.  If you aren't using Spring 3 you can simply inject the JdbcTemplate when you define your DAO bean.

```
public class MyDao {
    @AutoWired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}
```